# Launch configuration in VS Code to connect to a Chrome instance which runs on a different computer?

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, chrome-remote-debugging

I am aware that there is a million of questions which ask (and get answered) how to launch Chrome or attach to it and then debug a web site from within VS Code.

I have nearly the same question, but in my case, **the browser which should be debugged runs on a different computer**.

[Microsoft states that this is possible](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging), and the IntelliSense popups in the launch configuration editor make me believe it. However, I've never seen an example of it, and haven't had success myself when trying it a few times in the past, although I've put quite some time into that subject.

Specifically, **in a Windows 10 system which has Chrome installed**, I do the following:

- Close all instances of Chrome and use the Windows task manager to verify that no instances are active any more
- As a non-administrative user, open a command line window and enter the following command:

  `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9229`
- In the Windows task manager, in the list which shows the running tasks, add the full command line column and verify that Chrome is running with the correct command line parameter
- Load the website in question (`https://website.local`) into Chrome. That website is served by a fully blown Apache stack which runs somewhere else.
- Turn off the Windows Firewall completely (for testing only of course)

**In a Linux system** (Debian buster in this case), I do the following:

- Install VS Code (without Chrome debugger extension, because it is deprecated)
- In VS Code, create the launch configuration shown below
- Run the (only) entry from that launch configuration

A few seconds after this action, VS code throws the following error:

```
Cannot connect to the target at odo.local:9229: Could not connect to debug target at http://odo.local:9229: Could not find any debuggable target.
```

Please note that `odo.local` is the FQDN of the Windows PC where Chrome runs.

The following is the complete `launch.json` with comments and empty lines being the only things which have been removed. Of course, I also have tried every combination of other attributes and values which halfway would make sense, using the IntelliSense popups as a guideline, but nothing worked. In every case, VS Code threw the error mentioned above.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [    
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Chrome on ODO",
            "address": "odo.local",
            "port": 9229,
            "urlFilter": "https://website.local/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I need to change that launch configuration to make VS Code connect to Chrome on the different PC and start debugging there?

Comment: hi, did find any solutions to this?